# Source vs Static Network Address Translation

Tags: nat

Terminology in my research makes it unclear whether Source NAT(SNAT) and Static NAT(also SNAT) are the same concept and/or what would noteable differences or advantages of either be?

Comment: @womble this posting led me to create this post. Why is it on topic and mine not? https://serverfault.com/questions/119365/what-is-the-difference-between-a-source-nat-destination-nat-and-masquerading please take the hold off. Thank you

Comment: This is a longstanding problem on SE. The rules are enforced arbitrarily.

Comment: They're different questions, and that one was asked *seven and a half years ago*, and standards change over time.

Comment: @womble So in the pursuit of knowledge can you say that the answer in that post is no longer accurate?

Answer (score 2):

I never use the acronym SNAT because it's confusing. Usually it means "source NAT" which is not necessarily the same as static NAT.

Comment: Tx...that is what I am finding, and trying to understand that difference.

Comment: The meaning of "Source NAT" is context dependent. It can mean "perform a translation if the source address is x" or it can mean "translate the source address to x".